# How to replace/overwrite values

Tags: sql, sas

If I have a table like this called myTable:

```
        | Var1 | Var2 | Var3 | Var4 | Var5   |
+-------+------+------+------+------+--------+
| Name1 | 1.1  | 1.2  | 0    | 03   | 201805 |
| Name1 | 1.1  | 1.2  | 0    | 03   | 201803 |
| Name2 | 2.1  | 2.2  | 0    | 03   | 202001 |
| Name3 | 3.1  | 3.2  | 3    | 01   | 202002 |
```

How would I write a query that overwrite/updates all `Name1` rows with the `Var1` and `Var2` values from `Name2` given that the rest of the variables matches and only do it on the condition that `Var5` is in a desired time interval, like `201805` -> `202001`?

Comment: Do you want to overwrite values for Name1 only? Or is the problem more general?

Comment: It is more general, I might want to update all Name1 variables with Name2 values, and also might want to update Name3 with Name5 values within this interval as well

Comment: So how do you know which Names should overwrite and which names should be overwritten given your logic?

Comment: That is something I want to be able to choose. Say that there are only Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4 and Name5, Name6, then say you could only overwrite Name1, Name2, Name3 and they can only be overwritten with Name4, Name5, Name6

Answer (score 1):

In SAS `Proc SQL` the query is a bit arduous.

```
data have;
input 
  name $ Var1   Var2   Var3   Var4   Var5: yymmn6.; 
format var5 yymmn6.;
datalines;
  Name1   1.1    1.2    0      03     201805  
  Name1   1.1    1.2    0      03     201803  
  Name2   2.1    2.2    0      03     202001  
  Name3   3.1    3.2    3      01     202002  
;

proc sql;
  create table rewrites as 
  select two.var1, two.var2 
  from have as one join have as two
  on one.var3 = two.var3 
   & one.var4 = two.var4
  where one.name = 'Name1' and two.name = 'Name2' 
   & one.var5 between '01may2018'd and '31jan2020'd
   & two.var5 between '01may2018'd and '31jan2020'd
  ;

  update have
  set 
    var1=(select var1 from rewrites)
  , var2=(select var2 from rewrites)
  where name = 'Name1'
   & var5 between '01may2018'd and '31jan2020'd
  ;
quit;

%let syslast = have;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the SQL 'LEAD()' function.

There are some nice examples [here](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-lead-function/#:%7E:text=SQL%20Server%20LEAD()%20is,next%20row%2C%20and%20so%20on.)
Example from this URL:

```
    SELECT 
    month,
    brand_name,
    net_sales,
    LEAD(net_sales,1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY brand_name
        ORDER BY month
    ) next_month_sales
FROM 
    sales.vw_netsales_brands
WHERE
    year = 2018;
```

Basically you can select the values from the next row.

For the condition on var5, simply put it in the WHERE clause.

Comment: SAS's `proc sql` does not support window functions. It's SQL dialect is limited to [ANSI-1992](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/63043/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0corah7t43hy7n1r7efplde5c8z.htm) with SAS methods.